# C# square brackets and greater/less than

Tags: c#, .net, f#

In C#, you might see things such as:

```
[<DllImport("myUnmanagedDLL.dll")>]
```

or a similar line (but without the greater/less than symbols):

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("MyProject")]
```

I know that the first is called an attribute (it has gt and lt signs) and can be used to add a sort of metadata to methods, types, etc, but what does the syntax of the second mean? I'm trying to translate something with this syntax to F# -- namely, this line:

```
[MonoMac.Foundation.Register("AppDelegate")]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but what does the syntax of the second mean?

This means that the attribute is being applied to the assembly, not to a type (class or struct) or member.

In F#, the line you're trying to translate should be:

```
[<MonoMac.Foundation.Register("AppDelegate")>]
```

Without seeing more, it's impossible to tell where this should be applied, however (a type, a method, etc).  I suspect this would go on your `type` definition in F#, though, given that this is typically used on a C# class.

On a side note, `[<DllImport("myUnmanagedDLL.dll")>]` is not valid C# - that's F# syntax.  C# uses `[Attribute]` for attributes (and VB.Net uses `<Attribute>`).

Comment: @Jwosty See also the section "Attribute Targets" on the page [MSDN Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw).

Answer (score 6):

In case it's helpful—in F#, assembly level attributes are typically applied to an empty `do` block:

```
[<assembly: AssemblyTitle("MyProject")>]
do ()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing C# with VB.NET syntax

In VB.NET it's `<DllImport("myUnmanagedDLL.dll")>` while in C# it's `[DllImport("myUnmanagedDLL.dll")]` without the greater than or less than signs.

The second is an assembly attribute, it's used to apply an attribute to the entire assembly, instead of just a particular class, method or property

Comment: FYI - The syntax he's showing is the F# syntax:  `[<FooAttribute>]`  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233179.aspx

Comment: @ReedCopsey ah, I thought he said it was C#, *In C#, you might see things such as:*, now it makes more sense

Comment: Yeah - the OP had an odd wording in the original